# how do I want the query to combine with charindex?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * From V_Product

orderNumber  | ProductCode                           | orderDate    | status

10100 | S18_1749,S18_2248,S18_4409,S24_3969 | 2003-01-06 |Shipped 
10101 | S18_2325,S18_2795,S24_1937,S24_2022 | 2003-01-09 |Shipped

--------------------------------------------------------------------

select *From  products 

productCode | productName | productLine | productScale

S10_1678 | 1969 Harley Davidson Ultimate Chopper | Motorcycles | 1:10
S10_1949 | 1952 Alpine Renault 1300 |Classic Cars | 1:10

-----------------------------join---------------------------------------

  select *From  products a inner join V_Product b 
  on( a.productCode = b.ProductCode or a.productCode = substring(b.ProductCode,CHARINDEX(',',b.ProductCode)+1,8))
```

how do I want all productcode to be combined using charindex not just one ?

Comment: The best approach would be to stop shoving delimited values like this in your view. It causes all sort of pain and anguish to get data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM products a
INNER JOIN V_Product b ON a.ProductCode = b.ProductCode OR b.ProductCode LIKE '%' + a.ProductCode + '%'
```

Comment: This works but sheds light on the design problem. This query has to use leading wildcards which renders the query nonSARGable and any indexing on this column is fruitless. Fixing the design of V_Product is the best approach.

Comment: @Sean Lange, I'm agree with you. To have ProductCodes stored in this way is a pain, and you will have to fight with inaccurate joins, like the example I shared.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!  Don't store lists of things in a string!  That is not the SQL way to store multiple values.  You should have a table with one row per order number and product code.

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  If so, you can use `like`:

```
select *
from  products p inner join
      V_Product vp
     on ',' + vp.productCode + ',' like '%,' + p.ProductCode + ',%';
```

There is no need to compare the columns with `=`; `like` takes care of that.

Note that this is "delimiter-safe".  So if you have two product codes, S-100 and S-1000, they will not be confused.